# Android - IF Statement using Spinner while Textview obtained from JSON

Tags: android, if-statement, spinner, android-volley

Despite following code tutorials I can't find any working code to solve my problem.

I want to use a toast when user chooses an item in spinner they then get [this json link](http://zxccvvv.netne.net/dosen.php)

My code:

```js
private void requestJsonObject(){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, PATH_TO_SERVER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson mGson = builder.create();
                spinnerData = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, DataObject[].class));
                //display first question to the user
                spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                assert spinner != null;
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this, spinnerData);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if(Text.equals("ardi halim")){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else if(Text.equals("indah")){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Testing Indah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
```

why my toast not show in the screen when i tap **ardi halim**??

What is wrong with my code?

*thanks to @mmmartinnn who has been advised to be edited*

Comment: Did you add `stringRequest` to the Volley Queue?

Comment: yes i had `stringRequest`, and this is the code `queue.add(stringRequest)`,

Comment: put a breakpoint and inspect the result of `String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();` It is probably not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if the if-statements do not work, then `String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();` is not what you expect, and you should be `Log`-ing that value to see what it actually is.

---

Here's an alternative approach to get the data that you've selected on the spinner.

Declare the adapter & listener **outside** the Volley request.

```
private SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter;
private Spinner spinner;
private List<DataObject> spinnerData = new ArrayList<DataObject>();

private static final GsonBuilder GSON_BUILDER = new GsonBuilder();
private final Gson mGson = GSON_BUILDER.create();

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
   ...

    //display first question to the user
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    assert spinner != null;
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this, spinnerData);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Now, when you set this listener, you can access the data from either `spinnerAdapter` or `spinnerData` with `getItem` or `get` method, respectively, with the `int position` to get the selected data.

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // For example
            DataObject selected = spinnerData.get(position);
            String namaDosen = selected.getNama_dosen();

            if(namaDosen.equals("ardi halim")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Also, don't forget to call `requestJsonObject()` at some point.

And, you simply need to update the spinner data & adapter inside the volley request instead of recreating the adapter and setting the listener for each volley request.

```
private void requestJsonObject(){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, PATH_TO_SERVER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            spinnerData.clear();
            spinnerData.addAll(Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, DataObject[].class)));
            spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: I assume getting the data inside the selection listener is the issue here.

Comment: the part that fixes the issue in your code is accessing the data object in its explicit type instead of calling `toString` on an `Object`, so the key part is to have the object `List` typed and declared outside. The adapter part is not relevant.

Comment: I do not know what `SpinnerAdapter` is, but looks like a `ArrayAdapter` subclass based on the constructor used. `getItem` would be a proper alternative to `get` on the list.

Comment: i have this error after i've tried ur code @cricket_007, `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void flix.yudi.combobox.SpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference`, do you know what happened? i think `spinnerData.clear()` who made it

Comment: You need to have `spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter` somewhere in the `onCreate`, as I have in my answer

Comment: @yudi *i think spinnerData.clear() who made it* -- No, read the error... It tried to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on a null object, which means the `spinnerAdapter` is not initialized.

Comment: ohh i tought `spinnerData.clear()` is the code to clear a list in spinner so `notifyDataSetChanged()` didn't see any text in spinner,

but sir, where should i put the `requestJsonObject()`??, should i put it `onCreate` like that?

Comment: **_you made it man!_**, thanks to help me, i just missed some declaration while i tried your code, now i can go to the next step